# unable to quit for loop python 2.7. for loop going on for ever

Tags: python, python-2.7

I don't know why but the following loop is infinite. I am trying to loop through i and j in sequence till nxt and nyt. but this code is looping for ever and i dont know the way out. P.S : I am not computer science student and is still figuring out coding any help is much appreciated.

```
    #unperturbed residuals
    for i in range(0,nxt):
      if i==nxt:
        break
      for j in range(0,nyt):
           if index[i,j]!=0:
             ronp, rwnp, 
              rgnp=residual.residual(po,sw,sg,i,j,boold,bwold,bgold,
                                    swold,sgold,rsoold,rswold,index, 
                                    delx, dely, depth, phi, kx, ky, 
                                    ax, ay, h, delt, qo, nxt, nyt, welin, 
                                    Vb, pvtgas, pvtoil, pvtw, relpermgo, 
                                    relpermow, time, it,fmult)
             ronp1+= (ronp,);rwnp1+=(rwnp,);rgnp1+=(rgnp,)
             rnp+=(ronp,rwnp,rgnp)
```

Comment: What values of `nxt` and `nyt` are you using?

Comment: Small correction: `range(0,x)` is the same as `range(x)`. Also, the last value is `x-1` not `x`.

Comment: Thanks;) i incorporated that, but still the problem remains, while debugging for loop goes on . According to me it should quit after i,j reaches nxt , nyt respectively. Inner loop (j ) is working fine . problem is in outer loop(i).

Comment: I think i got the error. I have the statement :  while err>1e-3: before first for line and this is what is causing the error.

Comment: `for` loops over finite sequences will *always* terminate, so if you have an endless loop it's nearly always a `while` loop or your loop is not infinite but "only" takes a really long time. (You can actually have infinite `for` loops if you iterate over "strange things", but as long as you only use "basic python" this won't happen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you haven't said what happens during the residual.residual function with all of those parameters. This shouldn't matter in python 2 however, unless you use `xrange` instead of `range`. By definition these `for` loops will terminate. try setting a counter because they might just be going very slowly.

Also, you don't need the `if i==nxt` because, so long as `nxt` isn't decreasing, the `for` loop will have already terminated.

If you are using Python 3 (contrary to the post tag) then make sure that `nxt` isn't being increased.